# Is it possible to use $array=() in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

Two things, first this is my first question in this forum and I do apologise if the formating is all over the place. Second I have not written that many bash scripts, and it tend to be quite a long time between the scripts I produce.

That said, here is my question.

Is it possible to do something like this in bash (Clear array $array contains):
    `$array=()`

Basically this is what I would like to do. I have a variable with array variable names in it:

```
array1=()  
array2=()  
arrayList="array1 array2"  


# In a function far far away
for array in $arrayList
do  
    eval arr=("\"\${$array[@]\"")  

    for index in ${!arr[@]}
    do
        echo "${arr[$index]}"
    done
    # Here is the big "?", I like to clear the array that $array refers to.
    $array=()  
done
```

My arrays contain strings that include "" (space) and this is why I use the `eval` statement. Not sure it's needed but at least it's working. The script is more or less working as I want it too, but I need to clear the arrays in the `$arrayList`, and I rather not hardcode it somewhere, even though that would be easy.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 re: use of eval -- short form is that it's really not an advised practice.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I read that `eval` is not a recommended way to go since you can inject bad stuff in it, or even do some stupid stuff yourself if not careful what you `evel`. I will consider swaping it for another solution, even though this script will only be used by myself.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is associative arrays. They're available in bash 4.

Comment: @Dunes Hmm, you are probably right. Was just reading about them on the link to [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) that Charles Duffy provided in his answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do is just `unset` them. An unset variable will act identically to an empty array in most contexts, and `unset $array` ought to work fine.

Comment: You mean it could it be that easy? :) I kind of thought it would just unset the $array variable leaving $array1 and $array2 intact. But after testing your suggestion it do looks promising. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Qben `unset array` would unset the array variable itself; `unset $array` works as-advertised.

Comment: @Qben: When you `unset` indirectly like that I recommend quoting the variable: `unset "$array"`

Comment: Using unset will cause you to lose any properties of the variable. For example, I had a local variable, I unset it, and now it is no longer local and breaks everything. As much as it pains me, `eval "$1=()"` is the only thing that works for me :-\

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `$foo=bar` *ever* -- that isn't how indirect assignments in bash work. Unfortunately, while being able to do indirect array assignments is an available feature in ksh93, it isn't a formally documented available feature in bash.

Quoting [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) (which should be read in full if you're interested in knowing more about using indirect variables in general):

> We are not aware of any trick that can duplicate that functionality in POSIX or Bourne shells (short of using [eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), which is extremely difficult to do securely). Bash can almost do it -- some indirect array tricks work, and others do not, and we do not know whether the syntax involved will remain stable in future releases. So, consider this a use at your own risk hack.
>
> ```
> # Bash -- trick #1.  Seems to work in bash 2 and up.
> realarray=(...) ref=realarray; index=2
> tmp="$ref[$index]"
> echo "${!tmp}"            # gives array element [2]
>
> # Bash -- trick #2.  Seems to work in bash 3 and up.
> # Does NOT work in bash 2.05b.
> tmp="$ref[@]"
> printf "<%s> " "${!tmp}"; echo    # Iterate whole array.
> ```

However, clearing is simpler, as `unset $array` will work fine.

Comment: I dont think he wants dereferencing, he just wants to empty the array

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter sure, but but answering only how to empty an array will leave someone wondering whenever they're trying to do something else. I've added a directly-on-point answer, but think there's value to answering the larger question of "what should I do instead of `$array=...`"?

Comment: Indirect assignments can be done like this: `declare $foo=bar`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson ...or with `printf -v "$foo" '%s' bar`, or with any of the other mechanisms given in the linked FAQ. It's not hard for non-array variables -- "You can't do `$foo=bar` ever" was meant only to mean that assignments with a `$` on the left side aren't valid even for non-arrays, not that no working syntax existed anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
array=()
```

It clears the array. I guess that is what you wanted..

Comment: No, it's not, you missed the point. The question is about indirection.